# WPF: Printing DataGrid in multiple pages

Tags: wpf, printing, datagrid, multipage

I have DataGrid that needs to be printed in multiple pages both horizontally and vertically.  Based on exhaustive searching the closest solution i have is the one found @http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138233/Custom-Data-Grid-Document-Paginator.  However, if DataGridTemplateColumn having ComboBox as its content is printed, the resultant print output is blank combobox.  Below is the screenshot of the print,

http://www.filedropper.com/datagridprint

Below is the code used to create a template column while printing,

```
private FrameworkElement GetTableCell(Grid grid, DataGridColumn column, object item, int columnIndex, int rowIndex)
    {
        FrameworkElement visualElement = null;
        if (column is DataGridTemplateColumn)
        {
            DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = column as DataGridTemplateColumn;
            ContentControl contentControl = new ContentControl();
            contentControl.Focusable = true;
            contentControl.ContentTemplate = templateColumn.CellTemplate;
            contentControl.Content = item;

            contentControl.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, columnIndex);
            contentControl.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowIndex);

            visualElement = contentControl;
        }
```

The above code basically creates new content control and adds the CellTemplate associated with the grid to the newly created content, which does not work.  I would like to know if there is a fix for the above code, if not, is there a working solution that would print DataGrid into multiple pages (WYSIWYG).

Thanks for your help.